# NSDictionary and plist

Tags: plist, nsdictionary, nslog

I have a plist file with string keys and number values. I think I managed to fill an NSDictionary object with the plist contents just fine with the code:

```
NSBundle* bun = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString* path = [bun pathForResource:@"Tempos" ofType:@"plist"];

tempos = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Now, here's the part I don't understand.

```
id object = [tempos objectForKey:@"Allegro"];
NSLog(@"bpm: %@", object);
```

Outputs the desired number, `168`.

```
NSInteger beats = (NSInteger)[tempos objectForKey:@"Allegro"];
NSLog(@"bpm: %ld", beats);
```

Instead outputs, `43203`.

More importantly, when I try

```
bpm = (NSInteger)[tempos objectForKey:@"Allegro"];
```

I get `43203` assigned to `bpm`. How do I get `168` assigned to `bpm` instead??

Comment: Just curious, does anyone know why 43203 was being outputted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using this should work:

```
int beats = [[tempos objectForKey:@"Allegro"] intValue];
NSLog(@"bpm: %i", beats);
```